# Return without memory leak

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I try to write a function which converts a `char*` to a `wchar_t*` to simplify multiple steps in my program.

```
wchar_t* ConvertToWString(char* str)
{
    size_t newStrSize = strlen(str) + 1;
    wchar_t* newWStr = new wchar_t[newStrSize];
    size_t convertedChars = 0;
    mbstowcs_s(&convertedChars, newWStr , newStrSize, str, _TRUNCATE);
    
    
    return newWStr; // I know i need to call "delete[] newWStr;" but then I can't return the converted string...
}
```

The function works but it is *obviously* memory leaking. Does someone know another way how to convert a `char*` to a `wchar_t*`?

My issue is that the function needs to handle different string lengths.

Right now I am using a workaround with a fixed buffer but that can't be the only solution:

```
wchar_t* ConvertToWStringUgly(char* str)
{
    wchar_t buffer[1024]; // fixed array for 1023 wchars
    size_t newStrSize = strlen(str) + 1;
    size_t convertedChars = 0;
    mbstowcs_s(&convertedChars, buffer, newStrSize, str, _TRUNCATE);

    return buffer; // This is working but not really a good way
}
```

Comment: Return `std::wstring`?

Comment: Well, *someone* has to allocate the memory. If it isn't the function, then it'll have to be the caller. But you can work around this by using a *data type* that manages the memory, such as `std:;wstring` (and for that matter, having `std::string` in the first place for the char-sized data). BTW: it is *undefined behaviour* to return a pointer to a local buffer like that - `wchar_t buffer[1024]` is *stack-allocated*, and thus *does not exist* after `return`. You would need to make it `static`, or use a global.

Comment: I think you would be better served at this point by looking up a tutorial on C++ memory management than trying to ask specific questions like this.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Returning the buffer is no problem, because it's always instandly copied in a new variable. It's intended to be a stack variable in another function. std::wstring can be the solution.

Comment: maybe you should return `std::shared_ptr`?

Comment: *"Returning the buffer is no problem"*. It is actually, your "fixed" version lead to UB returning dangling pointer, whereas the problematic function is fine but C-style (which might so be fixed by any smart pointer or appropriate container).

Comment: ```std::wstring ConvertToWString(std::string oldStr)
{
 std::wstring newWStr(oldStr.begin(), oldStr.end());
 return newWStr;``` This seems to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Classic. Use the C++ power ! ... Destructors freeing allocated memory

Instead of your

```
wchar_t buffer [1024];
```

why not declare and use a Wstr class, looking approximately like this (maybe malloc and free to used instead of new and delete ?):

```
class Wstr {
public :
  Wstr () : val_ ((wchar_t*) NULL), size_ (0) {}
  ~Wstr () {
    if (val_ != (wchar_t*)NULL) {
      delete[] val_;
      val_ = (wchar_t*)NULL;
    }
  }
  Wstr& operator = (const char*& str) {
    size_ = strlen(str) + 1;
    if (val_ != (wchar_t*) NULL) {
      delete [] val_;
      val_ = (wchar_t*) NULL;
    }
    size_t newStrSize = strlen(str) + 1;
    size_t convertedChars = 0;
    mbstowcs_s(&convertedChars, val_, newStrSize, str, _TRUNCATE);
    size_ = newStrSize;
    return *this;
  }
  //.. copy cons, op =, op ==, op != to be written
  wchar_t* val_;
  size_t size_;
};
```